# Как поднять регистр первой буквы значения, которое приходит в переменную?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть такая строчка

> ```
> echo "<a href=\"models.php?marka=$row[0]\">$row[0]</a>";
> ```

В массив $row[0] приходят строки с маленькой буквы. Подскажите, как поднять первую букву в верхний регистр?

Comment: Супер! Спасибо большое! Работает. Да. Только с латинскими предполагается работа.
____
Куда тут + в карму ставить? Не разберусь никак)

Comment: @Makdak, обычно пишут ответы, которые можно принять - нажать на галку возле самого подходящего ответа. Я просто пишу вот мелкие подсказки комментариями, а ответы стараюсь писать достаточно объемными и полновесными.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Ну это самый настоящий полновесный ответ в данном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Если работа с нелатинским символами не предполагается

```
echo '<a href="models.php?marka=' . $row[0] . '">' . ucfirst($row[0]) . '</a>';
```

Comment: Дорогой @Etki, если вы отвечаете на вопрос, хоть и кратко, без обложки, иллюстраций и оглавления, пусть это будет ответ, который можно принять.

К вашей меткой подсказке и добавить нечего )